# How to use OpenGL in Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

When I want to compile the project there is some warnings:
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(34): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'CreateRenderingContext'
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(34): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'opDoubleBuffered'
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(35): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'ActivateRenderingContext'

All libraries are imported(

P.S. This code works in Delphi 7.

Comment: Well, looks like the identifiers are not declared. Just like the compiler says. Are they declared anywhere?

Comment: CreateRenderingContext is procedure and [opDoubleBuffered] is in:
rc:=CreateRenderingContext(dc,[opDoubleBuffered],32,24,0,0,0,0);

Comment: If the compiler could see the declarations, it would not give those error messages. Clearly the compiler cannot see them.

Comment: Most of all, I put the library at the wrong place, thanks.